# Segmentation fault when passing array of pointers to function

Tags: c++, hash, chaining

I am currently working on a homeworking question and I have been trying to figure out why I keep getting a segmentation fault (core dump). I have narrowed it down to accessing an array within a function. The goal of the program is to store words from a book in a separate chaining hash table. And we can't use STL.

The array in question (Table size is 30000):

```
Node* hashTable = new Node[TABLE_SIZE];
```

The Node:

```
struct Node {
  unsigned int hash = 0;
  string word;
  int count;
  Node* next;
};
```

the function prototype that I am using:

```
int insert(unsigned int hash, string word, Node* table[]);
```

How I am calling the function:

```
int result = insert(hashIndex, word, &hashTable);
```

The function itself (yes I know its not pretty):

```
int insert(unsigned int hash, string word, Node* table[])
{
  unsigned int hashIndex = hash;

  Node* newNode;
  newNode->hash = hashIndex;
  newNode->count = 1;
  newNode->word = word;
  newNode->next = nullptr;

  if(table[hashIndex % TABLE_SIZE] == nullptr) {
    table[hashIndex % TABLE_SIZE] = newNode;
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    if(table[hashIndex % TABLE_SIZE]->hash == hash) {
      table[hashIndex % TABLE_SIZE]->count++;
      return 2;
    }

    Node* indexPtr = table[hashIndex % TABLE_SIZE]->next;
    while(indexPtr) {
      if(indexPtr->hash == hash) {
        indexPtr->count++;
        return 2;
      }
      indexPtr = indexPtr->next;
    }

    indexPtr->next = newNode;
  }

  return 1;
}
```

Whenever I try to access anything within `hashTable` I get a segmentation fault. Any help and criticism would be appreciated.

MINIMUM REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
  unsigned int hash = 0;
  string word;
  int count;
  Node* next;
};

const string FILENAME = "C:/Users/Matthew/CLionProjects/p5/ulyss12.txt";
const int TABLE_SIZE = 30011;

string processWord(string word);
string removePunctuation(string word);
unsigned int hashFunc(string value);
int insert(unsigned int hash, string word, Node* table[]);
void displayHash(Node* table[]);

int main()
{
  Node* hashTable = new Node[TABLE_SIZE];
  string word = "HelloWorld";
  unsigned int hash = hashFunc(word);
  insert(hash, word, &hashTable);

  return 0;
}

string processWord(string word)
{
  if(word.length() >= 5) {
    word = removePunctuation(word);
  }
  else {
    return "";
  }

  return word;
}

string removePunctuation(string word)
{
  int i = 0;
  while(ispunct(word[i])) {
    word.erase(i, 1);
    i++;
  }

  i = word.length()-1;
  while(ispunct(word[i])) {
    word.erase(i, 1);
    i--;
  }

  return word;
}

int insert(unsigned int hash, string word, Node* table[])
{
  unsigned int hashIndex = hash;

  Node* newNode = new Node();
  newNode->hash = hashIndex;
  newNode->count = 1;
  newNode->word = word;
  newNode->next = nullptr;

  if(table[hashIndex % TABLE_SIZE] == nullptr) {
    table[hashIndex % TABLE_SIZE] = newNode;
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    if(table[hashIndex % TABLE_SIZE]->hash == hash) {
      table[hashIndex % TABLE_SIZE]->count++;
      return 2;
    }

    Node* indexPtr = table[hashIndex % TABLE_SIZE]->next;
    while(indexPtr) {
      if(indexPtr->hash == hash) {
        indexPtr->count++;
        return 2;
      }
      indexPtr = indexPtr->next;
    }

    indexPtr->next = newNode;
  }

  return 1;
}

unsigned int hashFunc(string value)
{
  const char* str = value.c_str();
  int length = value.length();

  unsigned int hash = 5381;
  int i    = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < length; ++str, ++i)
  {
    hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + (*str);
  }

  return hash;
}
```

Comment: "...we can't use STL." Sigh. Another C+ course.

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: In `Node* hashTable = new Node[TABLE_SIZE];`, `hashtable` points at an array of `Node`s. In `int insert(unsigned int hash, string word, Node* table[])`, `table` is a pointer to an array of pointers to `Node`s. If you are stuffing `hashTable` into `table`, you're going to have a bad time since they are different types. Perhaps you should show how you are calling the function.

Comment: Hash tables should be sized with prime numbers. Do not use a number with a lot of factors.

Comment: I'm guessing the pointers in `hashTable` are uninitialised. Please show a [mre]

Comment: I think what you want is an array of pointers, not an array of literal `Node` objects. You should do `new Node*[N]`.

Comment: Flip, if you want to get a really low grade, use the C++ Standard Library and point out to your teacher that it is not the STL. Teacher love it when they have a wise guy in the class.

Comment: @user4581301 Technically the STL is dead, but the STandard Library lives on.

Comment: That and I should be more careful with sarcasm online. I might accidentally start up another Q-Anon.

Comment: @AlanBirtles updated to show minimum reproducable example

Comment: @user4581301 updated to show how function is called

Comment: `insert(hash, word, &hashTable);` Is what I expected. It passes in a pointer to a pointer to an array (`Node**`) which unfortunately looks just like the required pointer to an array of pointers (also `Node **`. Don't get me started. It was a great idea back in 1970, but hasn't aged well) and behaves totally differently. Borrowing from tadman's suggestion, you want `Node** hashTable = new Node*[TABLE_SIZE];` to get a pointer to an array of pointers and then `insert(hash, word, hashTable);`.

Comment: More detailed: `table[0]` would be the same as `hashtable`. But because `hashtable` is a single pointer, `table[1]` reaches outside of `hashtable`'s storage into some other poor variable's storage (or into dead space if there's nothing there) and [The Bad](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) happens. In this case it probably tries to use part of `string word` as if it was a `Node*` with horrible results. Mind you a crash isn't all that horrible. It beats the alternative of subtle and silent memory corruption that you don't know about until it's too late.

Comment: And one of these days I'll remember I can answer as well as comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to both @AlanBirtles, @user4581301, and @tadman for the answers that they provided. It turns out that I had not initialized the nodes within the array to anything, so a simple for loop going through the `hashTable` array and setting everything to nullptr, along with the suggestions from the aforementioned users fixed the problem I was having.

**SOLUTION**

```
  Node** hashTable = new Node*[TABLE_SIZE]{};
```

Credit it @Eljay for the suggestion to use the curly brackets instead of a for loop.

If there is any further issues that any of you have noticed. Please comment. Or something.

Comment: @Eljay Thanks! Updated answer